# Editable custom field in WP Admin Dashboard

Tags: custom-field, dashboard

How to create an editable custom field in WordPress Admin Dashboard?

Why? For example: admin changes the text of custom field from the dashboard, and this field updates in a div on the website.

Thank's!

Comment: You should look at the Customize API https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/customize-api/